# "EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\\Users\\<user>\\node_modules\\bufferutil\\prebuilds\\win32-ia32\\node.napi.node'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-install

I'm trying `npm i @solana/web3.js` but cant due to the EPERM error. I tried changing the `prefix` in config, reinstalling Node, updating NPM and Yarn but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cache clean and npm update to the latest with force work for me

```
npm cache clean --force

npm install -g npm@latest --force
```